# Android Speech to text on voice calls

Tags: android, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

Hello is it possible to have a speech to text option on calls wherein the receiver of the call will get a live transcript of that call. I have tried to read about IBM Watson's Speech to Text service but to no avail as it only has instructions on already recorded data. Can anyone help me out or is this not possible?

Comment: In real time?  That's going to be difficult-  most speech to text service require you to send data to a server for processing.  That means you'd need to record the data, send it to a server, and then get a response back.  There will be a lag, and you will need to record it first.  And there's no way in Android to directly get the call audio stream, so you're going to need to record from the mic and hope its loud/clear enough

Comment: may I know the best way to implement such a system?

Answer (score 0):

You can stream in audio, but you will need to make use of the web sockets API - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text#recognize-audio-websockets-

You open the web socket, send a `start` packet, then send the stream as you capture it as `data` packets, terminate with an `stop` packet. You will need to set `interim_results` to `true` if you want a transcript flow.